# The code in the then method is not executed and error handling is performed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a web app in React and firebase and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Here is my code

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { Link, useHistory, Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { db } from "../firebase"
import Dashboard from "../components/Dashboard"

export default function UpdateProfile() {
  const usernameRef = useRef()
  const emailRef = useRef()
  const passwordRef = useRef()
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
  const { updateUser, currentUser, updatePassword } = useAuth()
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const history = useHistory()

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords do not match")
    }

    if (passwordRef.current.value) {
      updatePassword(passwordRef.current.value)
    }

    const uid = currentUser.uid
    db.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.data() 
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        setError("")
        updateUser(usernameRef.current.value, emailRef.current.value, data)
        history.push('/dashboard')
      } catch {
        setError("Failed to update account")
      }
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Update Profile</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="username">
              <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                ref={usernameRef}
                required
                defaultValue={currentUser.username}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                ref={emailRef}
                required
                defaultValue={currentUser.email}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                ref={passwordRef}
                placeholder="Leave blank to keep the same"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                ref={passwordConfirmRef}
                placeholder="Leave blank to keep the same"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
              Update
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        <Link to="/">Cancel</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is the code for the user's edit function: enter a value in the form and press the button to run handleSubmit.

```js
  function updateUser(username, email, data) {
    const uid = data.uid
    db.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
      email: email,
      username: username,
    }, {merge: true})
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async(user) => {
      if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid
        console.log(uid)
        await db.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.data()
            setCurrentUser(data)
            setLoading(false)
          })
      }
    })
    
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])
```

And the following code rewrites the firestore data After this updateUser function is executed, we want to do a history.push in then of handleSubmit to redirect to /dashboard, but we want to get the console to say "success! in the console and the "failure! in the console and the message "success!" appears on the app.

When I looked at the firestore data, I found that the values I entered were properly reflected in the firestore.

This tells me that the then part of handleSubmit is not working, but I don't know why it's not working.

If you have a solution, I'd love to hear it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- Either `await` or put a `.catch` onto the `updateUser` Promise chain (the `try`/`catch` around it will only catch async errors if the Promise is `await`ed)
- Return the Promise from `updateUser`
- Pass a *function* to the `.then` callback - your `.then(console.log("success!!"))` invokes `console.log` *immediately* and passes `undefined` to the `.then`

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
        return setError("Passwords do not match")
    }

    if (passwordRef.current.value) {
        updatePassword(passwordRef.current.value)
    }

    const uid = currentUser.uid
    db.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.data()
            setLoading(true)
            setError("")
            return updateUser(usernameRef.current.value, emailRef.current.value, data);
        })
        .then(() => {
            // Success
            history.push('/dashboard')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setError("failed!!")
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false)
        });
}
```

```
function updateUser(username, email, data) {
    const uid = data.uid
    return db.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
        email: email,
        username: username,
    }, { merge: true })
        .then(() => console.log("success!!"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

However, after redirecting to /dashboard, I want to reflect the value I entered, but it's reflecting the value before I entered it.

How do I make the values reflected after redirecting to /dashboard?

Comment: What do you mean by `want to reflect the value I entered`? Are you logging a value somewhere or something?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. I've added some code.

This handleSubmit function is for the component that edits the user's information. When you enter a value into the form and click the submit button, the value entered by the handleSubmit function is passed to the updateUser function, which then references the data in the firebase collection in useEffect and displays it on the app.

However, the value entered in the form is reflected in the firestore, but after being redirected, the user's information is displayed before editing.